# How to include bootstrap template in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to include a bootstrap template on codeigniter code, so i included the template in views folder and then i called it in controller but i can't see the template in my page

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootsrtap Free Admin Template - SIMINTA | Admin Dashboad Template</title>
    <!-- Core CSS - Include with every page -->
    <link href="plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="plugins/pace/pace-theme-big-counter.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/main-style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body class="body-Login-back">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center logo-margin ">
              <img src="img/logo.png" alt=""/>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">                  
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                                <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     <!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
    <script src="plugins/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

this is login.php (in views folder)

```
---------------

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootsrtap Free Admin Template - SIMINTA | Admin Dashboad Template</title>
    <!-- Core CSS - Include with every page -->


</head>
```

Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct access allowed');


class Login extends CI_Controller

{

    public function index()

    {   
            $this->load->view('login');

    }



}
```

and this is login.php (in controllers folder)

please help me with this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well first off you should all ways have your assets out side of your application folder.

Because the .htaccess file that is inside the application folder blocks that

```
project > 
project > application
project > assets
project > system
project > index.php
project > .htaccess <!-- use a htaccess here for removing index.php
```

Second set your base_url in config > config.php

```
// You are recommend to do so in CI 3 + versions

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourprojectname/';
```

Third Auto load the url helper config > autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

> Controller Make sure your **class** and **file name** first letter only upper
>   case

As said here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Filename Example.php

```
<?php

class Example extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('example');
        $this->load->view('footer');

    }

}
```

Then create a header.php and footer.php and example.php view

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

header.php view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css');?>">
</head>
<body>
```

example.php view

```
Any content you need
```

footer.php view

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js');?>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is an example. Make a folder, that called is `assets`, paste all style, js resources into it.

Please show you console log tab. Example:

[image]

Comment: Check your $config['base_url'] if it is empty.

Comment: Please show your tree folder in your post, to make sure you did it on right way.

Comment: i checked $config['base_url] and its empty

Comment: Can you debugging resources not found URLs in developments tools of Firefox or Chrome. Paste a capture into your post, please.

Comment: yes i can't find any sources in my debugging tools in firefox. what can i do?

Comment: I want to understand your tree folder (what is the resources path). And console log.. (I've updated example).

Comment: I found out what the problem was.

Thank you so much for you efforts :D